# How many rational numbers are in the opening of this binomial: $(\sqrt3+\sqrt[3]2)^{100}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem, rational-numbers

[image]

> 73) *How many rational numbers are in the opening of the binomial?*
>
> $$(\sqrt3+\sqrt[3]2)^{100}$$

For the first time I solve such a question. My approach:

> $$
> \left\lbrace\begin{array}{ccccccl}
>  (\sqrt3)^{2m}×(\sqrt[3]2)^{3n}\in \mathbb{Q} 
> \\[1mm]
> 2m+3n=100
> \end{array}\right.\Longrightarrow 2m+3n=100 \Longrightarrow 2m+6k=100 \Longrightarrow m=50-3k,\left\{k≥0,m≥0  \right\} \Longrightarrow k=0,1,2,3,..,16  \Longrightarrow 16+1=17
> $$

Is this the correct way to find the answer?

Comment: Yes, you get the right answer.

Comment: Thank you! @GNUSupporter.

Answer (score 1):

Each term of $(a+b)^{100}$ is of the form $C(100,k)*a^{k}*b^{(100-k)}$.
In this case, $k$ will have to be even and $100-k$ will have to be a multiple of 3.

So, $k = 2r$  and  $100-k = 100-2r = 0 (\mod 3) ==> r = 2 (\mod 3)$

As $k$ varies from 0 to 100, $r$ varies from 0 to 50.

There are 17 such $r$ between 0 and 50  $(2 = 3*0+2, 5 = 3*1+2, ..., 50 = 3*16+2)$.

So, 17 of the 101 terms of the expansion are rational.